# json headers in api request causes rails to add extra object to params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what's going on here, but if I do:

```
curl http://192.168.1.27:3000/api/v1/scores.json
```

my controller's params are:

> {"controller"=>"api/v1/scores", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"json"}

but if I do:

```
curl http://192.168.1.27:3000/api/v1/scores -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

the params are:

> {"controller"=>"api/v1/scores", "action"=>"index", "score"=>{}}

Why is that "score" => {} getting added to the params and how can I stop that from happening?

**UPDATE**

Here is the rails server log for the first curl request:

> Started GET "/api/v1/scores.json" for 192.168.1.27 at 2015-12-29
>   23:40:52 -0800 Processing by Api::V1::ScoresController#index as JSON
>   Score Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "scores".* FROM "scores"  ORDER BY
>   "scores"."points" DESC LIMIT 10 Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views:
>   32.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)

and for the 2nd with the headers:

> Started GET "/api/v1/scores" for 192.168.1.31 at 2015-12-29 23:38:45
>   -0800 Processing by Api::V1::ScoresController#index as JSON   Parameters: {"score"=>{}}   Score Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "scores".*
>   FROM "scores"  ORDER BY "scores"."points" DESC LIMIT 10 Completed 200
>   OK in 40ms (Views: 30.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

Comment: Can you show the log from Rails for the 2 Curl request ? First 6-7 lines are enough to show...

Comment: where are the parameters for the first Curl .. See when you will make a JSON request Rails should add a root key like you see in the second case, why it didn't happen in the first case I am wondering.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html